# Convert UILabel subclass from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

how do i convert the following subclass code into swift 3.1.1
I've tried to convert myself but i get too many errors

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myTextLabels : UILabel


@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *overrideFontName;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat iphoneFontSize;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat ipadFontSize;
@end

#import "myTextLabels.h"

@implementation myTextLabels

- (void)setOverrideFontName:(NSString *)overrideFontName
{
   if (![_overrideFontName isEqualToString:overrideFontName])
{
    _overrideFontName = overrideFontName;

    self.font = self.font;
   }
}

- (void)setFont:(UIFont *)font
{
   NSString *overrideFontName = self.overrideFontName;
   if (overrideFontName != nil)
  {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:overrideFontName size:font.pointSize];
  }

   [super setFont:font];
 }

@end
```

tried various things but too many errors
here my attempt

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class myTextLabel:UILabel{

    @IBInspectable var overrideFontName: String = ""
    @IBInspectable var iphoneFontSize: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var ipadFontSize: CGFloat = 0.0

    func setOverrideFontName(_ overrideFontName: String) {
        if !(self.overrideFontName == overrideFontName) {
            self.overrideFontName = overrideFontName
            font = font
        }
    }

    func setFont(_ font: NSFont!) {
        let overrideFontName: String = self.overrideFontName
        if overrideFontName != nil {
            font = UIFont(name: overrideFontName, size: font.pointSize)
        }
        super.font = font
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Method 'setOverrideFontName' with Objective-C selector 'setOverrideFontName:' conflicts with setter for 'overrideFontName' with the same Objective-C selector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import UIKit

class myTextLabels: UILabel {
@IBInspectable private var _overrideFontName: String = ""
@IBInspectable var overrideFontName: String {
    get {
        return _overrideFontName
    }
    set(overrideFontName) {
        if !(_overrideFontName == overrideFontName) {
            _overrideFontName = overrideFontName
            font = font
        }
    }
}
@IBInspectable var iphoneFontSize: CGFloat = 0.0
@IBInspectable var ipadFontSize: CGFloat = 0.0

override func setFont(_ font: NSFont!) {
    let overrideFontName: String = self.overrideFontName
    if overrideFontName != nil {
        font = UIFont(name: overrideFontName, size: font.pointSize)
    }
    super.font = font
}
}
```

Comment: having tried your code , i now have more errors as follows

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'NSFont'

Comment: Comparing non-optional value of type 'String' to nil always returns true

Comment: UIFont can't work too ? The second error doesn't seem an error no ?

Comment: I Tried UIFont but it just kicks up even more moans and groans

Comment: Maybe you could try to delete the _

Comment: Write that : func setFont(font: UIFont!) {}